# Kubernetes nginx ingress accesses outside of cluster without using service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Apologies if this has been answered before, but I am a little confused on Ingress Nginx is working together with services.

I am trying to implement an nginx ingress in my Kubernetes environment.
So far I have an ingress-nginx-controller-deployment setup, as well as a deployment and service for the default backend. I still need to create my actual Ingress resources, the ingress-nginx-controller-service and also my backend.

`curl <NodeIP>`
returns `"default backend 404"` on port 80 for the Node which the ingress-nginx-controller-deployment is deployed on.
However, my understanding is that exposing anything out of the cluster requires a service (Nodeport/Loadbalancer), which is the duty of the ingress-nginx-controller-service.

My question is how is this possible, that I can access port 80 for my Node on my browser, which is *outside* the cluster?
Could I then deploy my backend app on port 80 the same way the above is done?

I feel like I am misunderstanding a key concept here.

default backend image: `gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0`

nginx-controller image: `gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.9.0-beta.3`

Comment: You could check this article: https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0

Also if you could you provide your ingress and service YAML it would be easier to answer your question. A few factors also depends from where you have your cluster, on-prem or locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you missed a [really good article](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) about how nginx-ingress expose to the world!

I short:
If you're using `hostNetwork: true` then you bypass the kubernetes network (kube-proxy). in a simple word, you bypass the container and orchestration network and just using the host network then the node with nginx-ingress container will expose port 80 to the world.

There are other ways that you can use to expose nginx port to outside of the cluster (node-port, network load balancer like MetalLB).

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense. I see that it'd be best to create the nginx ingress controller as a Daemonset then, so one pod per node (this does not seem to be too big of a problem). The downside I saw was the option `exposes every system daemon to the NGINX Ingress controller`, how big of a concern is this? Sorry am a bit new to a lot of concepts here.

Comment: Are there any downsides to using a self-provisioned edge? If I understand correctly, it's using the NodePort method, but setting up another network with reverse proxying  in front to avoid the high port ranges. Would there be any downsides to this?